# About EBS Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I Have a medium EC2 Instance on Amazon with 3 EBS (general purpose type)

```
On first EBS I have OS installed
On second EBS I have a Webserver and PHP app
On third EBS I have file storage
(invoices, services orders, and other company documents), in PDF format.
```

Document access is not frequently, around 100/250 documents per hour.

My question is, whats happen if i move storage to a COLD HDD?

I have checked out this document and I understand big change between EBS GENERAL and COLD HDD are IOPS
https://www.softnas.com/wp/support/aws-storage-guide/

```
            EBS GENERAL             COLD HDD
IOPS        10000                   250
Throughput  320mb/s                 250mb/s
```

Considering 250 IOPS (input/output operations per second) I believe there will be no problems if I move storage to COLD HDD, but I prefer some opinion by more experts.

Can we move? :-)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the **CloudWatch metrics** for the volumes and see if the bandwidth and IOPS are below the cold hdd performance. My feeling from your description is that it should be no issue but check the metrics first and also monitor it after the transition to `sc1` volume.